# Error:" ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS localhost redirected you too many times"

Tags: php, validation, popup, logout

I'm doing a pop-up login in home page (home.php). It can log in at first but after I clicked on the logout button the whole page went blank says"localhost redirected you too many times" and now the `home.php` cannot be access unless removing the php code. Both login and logout are at the same page (home.php). Can anyone explain to me what's wrong? I'm still new to php.

Here's the code:
outside html

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header("location: home.php");
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: home.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

inside body

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
      <div class="error success" >
        <h3>
          <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['success']; 
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
          ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <!-- logged in user information -->
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
        <p> <a href="home.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: The error message is obvious, you have a redirect loop. Can you post the `home.php` code?

Comment: This is in ```home.php```. Do you mean the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

this bug happens when the browser stuck in redirect loop. it's because of this code:

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header("location: home.php");
  }
```

If user not logged in the user will redirect to home.php , then the page will run again and the browser because of not logged in must redirect again to same page.

You can use many solutions to solve this , But i think the best solution is use another php file for login actions.

Comment: does it mean I have to create a login.php file and keep all these in that php file then change the header location into 'login.php'?

Comment: yeah,it will make your code cleaner, organized and will solve your issue.

Comment: will it affect the pop-up login form as it has been written in ```home.php```?

Comment: mostly no. but if anything happens, it can be easily fixed.

Comment: but how does it work? because if I create another php file it means it will redirect to another page right? but I'm doing a pop-up login form which means when I click on the login button it will pop-out a login form for users to login. :/

Comment: First you have to check if user is logged in. Then if not logged in you can bring up pop up form with HTML and  js. then send login information to login.php and validate.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 

  if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) 
  {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header("location: home.php");
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) 
  {

    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: home.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
  //Print Some session values
}
else
{
  //Login page code
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue maybe while destroying the session.

Comment: is this for the login?